# How to make two different service references implement the same interface?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, interface

I have the following scenario:

- Services Web Project (Web Application)

  - ServiceA.svc
  - ServiceB.svc
  - ExceptionResponseMessage.cs
- Interface Web project (Web Application)

  - Service References:

    - ServiceAServiceReference
    - ServiceBServiceReference

In both services (A and B) I have methods that returns the ExceptionResponseMessage class. In the interface web project, which I'll call "client", for easy reference, this class is generated two times:

- ServiceAServiceReference.ExceptionResponseMessage
- ServiceBServiceReference.ExceptionResponseMessage

I'd like to create a function in my client that will handle the response Message to see if there is any error and handle it correctly. Since i have two copies of the class, I would have to create two methods:

```
public static void HandleError(ServiceAServiceReference.ExceptionResponseMessage ex)
{
    (Method Implementation here)
}

public static void HandleError(ServiceBServiceReference.ExceptionResponseMessage ex)
{
    (Method Implementation here)
}
```

I'd like to avoid that, so I created an Interface in a different class library Project, which both Services and client project can access. The ExceptionResponseMessage implements this Interfaces.

The problem is that the client generated classes for "ExceptionResponseMessage", does not implements the interface. I've even created a self referencing "InnerException" property in the interface and in the object, like this:

```
public interface IExceptionResponseMessage {
    IExceptionResponseMessage InnerException { get; set; }
}

public class ExceptionResponseMessage : IExceptionResponseMessage
{
    public IExceptionResponseMessage InnerException { get; set; }
}
```

But when I check the client generated object, it says the InnerException property is of type Object, which shows the interface is not being respected in client.

Does anyone know how can I make the client classes implement the interface?

Comment: does the client have the assembly that contains the interface and implementation?  If not then you'd have to create an abstraction on the client.

Comment: The client have only the the assembly with the interface. The implementation is automatically generated by the service Reference.

Comment: Right, but with WCF if you have the actual class assembly it will use it... (I think...)

Comment: Otherwise you will have to deal with custom type.

Comment: The problem is that my ExceptionResponseMessage inherits from a ResponseMessage master class. This class and all its descendents are available by the server, but some of the classes has referentes to classes in the services project wich i can't put in this common library.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I don't like to recommend using `dynamic` due to the risk of failure at run-time, but it may be worth the risk here since you're already in an error handler anyways:

```
public static void HandleError(dynamic ex)
{
    //(Method Implementation here)
}
```

That way you can use properties and methods that are common to the exception types.  If you want intellisense, you can strong-type it during development and change to `dynamic` once the handler is complete.

The risk is if you use a method/property that does not exist, it fails at runtime.  You can reduce the effects of that error by handling the `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException` exception:

```
public static void HandleError(dynamic ex)
{
    try
    {
        //(Method Implementation here)
    }
    catch(Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException rbex)
    {
        // do something (or ignore)
    }
    // all other exceptions are bubbled up
}
```

A somewhat safer solution is to keep your overloads and make the `dynamic` method `private`:

```
public static void HandleError(ServiceAServiceReference.ExceptionResponseMessage ex)
{
    HandleErrorDynamic(ex);
}

public static void HandleError(ServiceBServiceReference.ExceptionResponseMessage ex)
{
    HandleErrorDynamic(ex);
}
private static void HandleErrorDynamic(dynamic ex)
{
    //(Method Implementation here)
}
```

That way you control what gets passed to the dynamic method and can write unit tests that would prevent runtime errors.

Comment: Thats an interesting solution, but has you said yourself, that's quite dangerous to loose the type check in compile type, but I might give it a try if i can't find a better solution.

Comment: you'd be better off overloading the `HandleError` method and calling common code from there.

Answer (score 1):

Forgo the service methods returning a class instance and instead return `string` xml response which can then be serialized in to the exception response class you are using.

Comment: thats an interesting Solution, but unfortunatelly it would be a much bigger change in my project structure at the time. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Marlon I figured that would most likely be your answer. I have been doing webservices for over ten years now and I always prefer (when I get the chance) to simply use versionable Xml.